# how to get the all zipcode within the 5miles of distance

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, geospatial

I would like all the zip codes which are within a 5 miles distance of a zip code input by the user.

Comment: This is rather very unclear, do you want to get all cordinates for a circle with given centre points and radius?

Comment: if i insert the pincode then from 5miles of distace i want all zipcode and i want to check it to the mongoose. and matched result i want to show as a result

Comment: Are you storing the cordinates of the people with the zipcode too in the database?

Comment: no. in database there is company details and zipcode. if i insert zipcode 123456 then i want to search which company is there near by on that zipcode within 5miles/5km distance

Comment: So for every zipcode you need to get the cordinates first, you can use yahoo Geoplanet for this

Comment: Why do you need to approximate a circle? Does not the `$maxDistance` argument to [**`$near`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/) do this for you?

Comment: As Neil says, MongoDB has this functionality out of the box.

Answer (score -1):

See you have the centre coordinates for the circle and radius of the circle say 5 miles, now for every cordinate point in database, check the distance between Centre  and that point by applying distance formula and check if it is less than radius,
In short,

```
C = point that is the center of the area
P = point we want to check for being inside the area
R = radius of the area

P is inside the area if

||P-C|| <= R
```

EDIT-

```
function getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2) {
  var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
  var dLat = deg2rad(lat2-lat1);  // deg2rad below
  var dLon = deg2rad(lon2-lon1); 
  var a = 
    Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
    Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * 
    Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2)
    ; 
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
  var d = R * c; // Distance in km
  return d;
}

function deg2rad(deg) {
  return deg * (Math.PI/180)
}
```

Comment: how can i implement it in nodejs.

Comment: @asmita i am updating my answer with the function to calculate distance between 2 cordinates

Comment: thanks sunny. but it still my issue not solve. how can i compare zipcode with this code?

Comment: ex- zipcode-12345
    distance - 5 miles
now i want to find all company detail which is near by this code and within this distance.

Comment: As i said for every zipcode you need to get its corresponding cordinates first, there are many webservices abailable for doing this. Best of Luck!

Comment: You can accept the answer in stackoverflow if it helped you!

Comment: It was a pleasure helping!

Comment: As this functionality already exists in MongoDB, it would be very inefficient to do this in nodejs on a larger result set.

Comment: @John Barça if there is lattitude and longitude i have then  how can i get the all zipcode withing 5miles of radius distance.

Comment: Read the $geoNear documentation. Come back after you have tried something if you still have doubts